# Is there universal if function in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas, series

I have three series. I need to do the following operation element-wise:

1. Compare values from the first and second series.
2. If first is larger take arc-sinus of the element from the third series.
3. Otherwise take arc-cosine.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
numpy.if(numpy.less(s1,s2),numpy.arcsin(s3),numpy.arccos(s3))
```

Unfortunately if does not work because `numpy.if` does not exist. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
np.where(s1<s2, np.arcsin(s3), np.arccos(s3))
```

---

For 1D inputs,

```
where(condition, [x, y])
```

is equivalent to

```
[xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in zip(condition,x,y)]
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I did not know that `<` works like that. I thought I needed to use `numpy.less` function. Why do we need `numpy.less` if `<` works with series.

Comment: @Roman An use case is if you have to pass the function as argument of an other function. You cannot do `call_a_function(<, a, b)` you must do `call_a_function(numpy.less, a, b)`. That's why there exist an `operator` module in python.

Answer (score 0):

unutbu did great. I propose one equivalent with no `where` (but with `numpy` anyway)

```
import numpy as np

s1=[2,1,2,5,4,6]
s2=[1,2,4,5,7,8]
s3=[0.1,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.1,0.1]

res = [xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in zip([si1<si2 
          for si1,si2 in zip(s1,s2)], list(np.arcsin(s3)), list(np.arccos(s3)))]
```

If you print the `zip()` you get this list

```
>>> 
[(False, 0.1001674211615598, 1.4706289056333368), (True, 0.41151684606748806, 1.1592794807274085), (True, 0.52359877559829893, 1.0471975511965979), (False, 0.64350110879328437, 0.9272952180016123), (True, 0.1001674211615598, 1.4706289056333368), (True, 0.1001674211615598, 1.4706289056333368)]
```

Take first item `(False, 0.1001674211615598, 1.4706289056333368)`: `2<1` indeed is false. So you will have `1.4706289056333368` as first value in `res`.

The result is

```
>>> res
[1.4706289056333368, 0.41151684606748806, 0.52359877559829893, 
            0.9272952180016123, 0.1001674211615598, 0.1001674211615598]
```